# Non-commutative rings without identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, rngs

I'm looking for examples (if there are such) of non-commutative rings without multiplicative identity which have the following properties:

1) finite with zero divisors

2) infinite with zero divisors

3) finite without zero divisors

4) infinite without zero divisors

I'll be grateful for any examples and hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $2)$: Infinite matrices (over any ring) where almost all entries are $0$.  For 1): $3\times 3$ matrices over a finite field with bottom row zero.

Comment: Almost all of our favorite non-commutative rings are matrix rings, and you can use pretty much any ring you want for their entries (even commutative rings)

Comment: Note that an ideal is any ring is a ring without identity.

Comment: @Myself: not necessarily! The ideal generated by a central idempotent $e$ in any ring has identity $e$. It is a unital ring but not a unital subring (in that it doesn't have the same unit as the overring).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Good point, I forgot about that. at AnyInterestedreader: see also [Pierce decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_decomposition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in Jared's comment, one may find easy examples of 1), 2), and 4) by taking non-unital subrings (such as left ideals or two-sided ideals) of rings with identity.

The most interesting request here is 3).  In fact, *any finite nonzero associative ring $R$ (possibly without identity) without zero divisors is a field*.

First, let's prove that $R$ in fact has an identity. Let $a \in R$ be a nonzero element. The function $f \colon R \to R$ defined by $\phi(x) = ax$ is injective, and since $R$ is finite, it's a bijection.  Again, because $R$ is finite, this bijection must have finite order.  Thus for some $d$, the function $\phi^d(x) = a^d x$ is the identity.  It follows that $a^d \in R$ is an identity element.

At this point, it's a standard exercise to show that a finite ring with identity and no zero divisors is a division ring. (Hint: think about the function above for any $a \in R$.)  And [Wedderburn's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem) states that any finite division ring is a field.

Comment: 1), 2) and 3) are clear to me know. But i still don't understand how to construct example for 4). Could you help me please?

Comment: How about the ideal $(x,y)$ in the free algebra $\math{Q} \langle x, y \rangle$?

Comment: I'll try to work with it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the bad TeX in the comment.  I meant to write: try the ideal $(x,y)$ in the free algebra $\mathbb{Q}\langle x,y \rangle$.  This ring has no zero divisors, so it's ideal can't have any zero divisors.