# Give an example of a finite non-commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Similarly, give an example of an infinite non-commutative  ring that does not have a unity.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394629/non-commutative-rings-without-identity

Comment: Matrices are good also for the infinite case: consider the $2\times2$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ where all entries are even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Think about matrix rings. They are usually non-commutative.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a semigroup with the multiplication: $ab=a$ for all $a,b$, and $F_2$ be the 2-element field. The semigroup ring $F_2S$ is a desired example.

Comment: Unless I'm sorely mistaken, it seems like this is pretty commutative. $ab = ba = 0$

Comment: @ Stahl: Yes, I wrote another example.