# Examples of rings satisfying some of the following properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to find at least one example of rings for every combination of the following properties [image]

Any ideas for the remaining cases?

Thank you

Comment: For a non-unital integral ring, take $2\mathbb{Z}$ for example.

Comment: For non-commutative unital integral ring, would $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ with $xy = -yx$ be ok ?

Comment: You can just take the free $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra on two generators. The notation $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ usually means $x$ and $y$ commute, so your proposed ring would be trivial.

Comment: For non-unital, non-integral, commutative, you can take $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Very many thanks

Comment: And for the final one, take $2R$ where $R$ is the free $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra on two generators.

Comment: This was discussed previously, at least in the noncommutative case, here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394629/non-commutative-rings-without-identity

Comment: Integral as in "no nonzero zero divisors" right?

Comment: That is what I meant, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three rows of ???? that you are apparently asking about.

For the first one occurring, you could use the ideal $(x)/(x^3)$ in $F_2[x]/(x^3)$. It is properly inside a local ring, so it doesn't have any idempotents aside from $0$, so no identity is there. It's not a domain since $x^3=0$.

For the second one, the integer quaternions (the subring of the quaternions generated by $i,j,k$ and the integers) (or also the Hurwitz quaternions) will do. They're a domain with identity that isn't commutative.

For the third one, you can take any nontrivial ideal of the integer quaternions.